# Spring Boot dynamic Cache Control header for different end points

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have added Cache-Control to endpoints response by adding following classes:

```
@Component
public class CacheControlInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    HandlerInterceptor cacheControlInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CacheControlInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/person/*");
    }
}
```

This works fine if all **"/person/*"** have same cache control headers. However, now we have a requirement that say different persons will have different **max-age** (e.g /person/1 is 300 & /person/2 is 1000). BTW, this requirement is due to the distributed cache having various expiry times for different personnels. How to archive this?

**PersonService** class will have the **max-age** value when retrieving a person. 
Can I add a **maxAge** attribute to **CacheControlInterceptor** which will be autowired in **PersonService**? I can then set it to **HttpServletResponse** in **preHandle(...)**. Just concerned that **CacheControlInterceptor** is singleton, does it work with multiple requests?

Another way I can think of is to set a **maxAge** attribute in **HttpServletRequest** which can then be used by **CacheControlInterceptor**. But how to expose it from **PersonService** to RestMapping handler method?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `max-age` is different between persons, i say keep all the common `Cache-Control` instructions in your `Intercepter` and add the `max-age` value in the service, after you actually load the `Person`. Something like following:

```
@RequestMapping("/person/{id}")
public void showPerson(@PathVaribale Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Person person = ...; // load the person from somewhere
    String currentCacheControl = response.getHeader("Cache-Control");
    if (currentCacheControl == null) currentCacheControl = "";
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", currentCacheControl + "max-age=" + person.getMaxAge());
}
```